# Using remote Red Hat AMQ 7 with Wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, wildfly-10, jboss-eap-7, activemq-artemis, amq

We are using Wildfly 10 and we want to use Red Hat AMQ 7 (standalone) remotely. I checked few documentation and found that ActiveMQ Artemis is also inbuilt in Wildfly 10, and I also configured it successfully to send and receive messages.

But as per our requirement, we want to use a remote AMQ broker so that it can be used as a centralized server and will be best suited in our enterprise requirement. Even I also want to understand the exact difference in using the ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in Wildfly and a remote Red Hat AMQ 7 instance, but I could not find enough information about it. If anyone is having any idea about it, please explain it.

I think there are three approaches to implement remote Red Hat AMQ.

1. Use the embedded ActiveMQ Artemis as a standalone server. I mean if we will install this Wildfly 10 in a separate server and if we can use that only for integration purpose and use the embedded ActiveMQ Artemis to connect with our Java application running on separate servers.
2. Install Red Hat AMQ 7.x as separate broker and connect it from the java application deployed on Wildfly 10. I checked Red Hat documentation and one point bothered me about this implementation as Red Hat claims "Currently AMQ 7.2 is only supported as a stand-alone broker. It has not be certified with EAP 7.0 or earlier. It is planned to be tested both as the internal broker of EAP 7.1 and as an external broker with EAP.". This is my preferred approach but I am not getting any documentation to implement it even Red Hat also not did it yet.
3. Install Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.x and integrate it from the application deployed in Wildfly 10.

I tried to get this information but as of now there is not much information available on internet for Artemis. It will be a great help if someone can explain the differences with pros and cons in above approaches.

Regard's
Ram

Comment: It's not clear whether or not you actually need/want commercial support. Red Hat AMQ 7 is a commercial product based (in part) on Apache ActiveMQ Artemis. Red Hat provides support for this product. However, Wildfly is a JBoss community project and Red Hat doesn't offer any support for it. To get support for a Java EE application server you'd need to use Red Hat JBoss EAP (the latest versions of which are based on Wildfly).  Please clarify in your question whether or not commercial support is important for you.

Comment: What kind of clients do you plan on using (what protocol & what language)?  ActiveMQ Artemis embedded within Wildfly only supports core JMS clients out-of-the-box whereas Red Hat AMQ 7 and standalone ActiveMQ Artemis support core JMS, OpenWire JMS, AMQP, STOMP, & MQTT out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin for your quick response.

We will use JBoss EAP7, core JMS protocol and spring.

We want to implement it ourself but there is not much help available on ineternet regading standalone AMQ 7 connection with JBoss EAP 7. As per RedHat documentation they also did not certify AMQ Artemis 7.2 working with Jboss EAP 7 as a standalone broker.

Could you please suggest if anyone implemented it this way and if there is any help available to connect JBoss EAP 7 with Standalone RedHat AMQ 7 using spring code.

If we could not do it ourself then we will involve RedHat.

Comment: It's important here to get your terminology correct to avoid confusion. There is no such thing as "AMQ Artemis."  There is Red Hat AMQ - Red Hat's commercial product, and there is ActiveMQ Artemis which is an Apache community project.  The message broker in Red Hat AMQ is based on ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: I believe that the latest versions of JBoss EAP 7 (e.g. 7.1 and 7.2 - which is currently in beta) were both certified with Red Hat AMQ as an external broker. However, you'd want to discuss this with Red Hat directly. One of the benefits of commercial support is being able to deal directly with authorities on the software you're using. You should take advantage of this benefit if you're using Red Hat products.